# Restore style class after restart

Tags: java, javafx, styles, restore

I want to save and restore the style class after restarting the application:

```
if(answered)
{
this.getStyleClass().add("GREEN");
}
```

So how can I save the style for the next start?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sdasdadas Just edited it.

Comment: What kind of application are you running?

Comment: @KS7X Standalone JavaFX Application

Comment: You could possibly write the style to a text file and read it upon restarting. Look into `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`

Comment: Your question is really too broad for this forum: it doesn't lend itself to a straightforward answer but more to a long discussion. In general though, the code snippet you posted suggests the style really depends on some state of the application (`answered`). So you should probably think about persisting the state of the application, and organizing your code so that when you restore the state you restore the style as well. There are many ways to persist the state: serialization, properties files, xml, yaml, json file formats, relational database, etc, and the choice depends on many factors.